# Magento newsletter subscribe gives 500 internal server error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, newsletter

Interesting bug. When I try to subscribe to magento newsletter, I end you getting an internal server error 500. However on refresh via the url, it gives me the thank you for subscribing and adds to the database too!

Can anyone shed some light into this or faced similar problems?

Julian

PS: Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please see your web servers log for errors. Usually the servers logs the occured php error which results in the 500 internal server error.

Many things could force this error. For example max_execution_time or memory overflow.